# Convert SQL query that uses CASE expression as a JOIN key to pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas, join, pandas-merge

```sql
SELECT a.year, a.country, b.amount
FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN table_b b
ON a.country=b.country
AND (CASE WHEN b.country = 'Europe' THEN b.year = 2022 ELSE b.year = 2023 END)
```

I am trying to transform this code into python. What I have already tried is using `pd.merge()` for the left join but unsure how to proceed with using case when in join condition of pandas merge.

Given the following input:

```py
table_a = pd.DataFrame({
    'country': ['Europe', 'Europe', 'USA', 'Africa'],
    'year': [2022, 2020, 2023, 2021]
})
table_b = pd.DataFrame({
    'country': ['Europe', 'USA', 'Africa', 'USA', 'Europe'],
    'year': [2023, 2022, 2022, 2023, 2022],
    'amount': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
})
```

the output should be:

```
  country  year  amount
0  Europe  2022    50.0
1  Europe  2020    50.0
2     USA  2023    40.0
3  Africa  2021     NaN
```

How do I make it work?

Comment: Skip the case expression, use regular AND/OR instead.

Comment: Thanks @jarlh, could you please share that as code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the condition is used to filter `table_b` before merging, we can go ahead and filter `table_b` first using the condition and merge later on `country` column.

```py
output = (
    table_a.merge(
        table_b.query("(country == 'Europe' and year == 2022) or (country != 'Europe' and year == 2023)"), 
        on=['country'], how='left', suffixes=('', '_'))
    [['year', 'country', 'amount']]
)
```

Using Nick's example, the above code produces the following output:

```
  country  year  amount
0  Europe  2022    50.0
1     USA  2023    40.0
2  Africa  2021     NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue with my code. You were indeed correct about the ordering of mask and merge.

Comment: Thanks @cottontail, I just noticed something, when I added a row in first df like 'Europe' and year 2020, sql gives a different result, you can check this example I've used [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/WQdeiOaB)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to include that condition in the merge, just use it to filter `b` before the merge. Something like this:

```py
mask = (df_b['country'] == 'Europe') & (df_b['year'] == 2022) | \
   (df_b['country'] != 'Europe') & (df_b['year'] == 2023)
out = df_a.merge(df_b[mask], on=['country'], how='left', suffixes=['', '_y']).drop(columns='year_y')
```

For example, with this sample data:

```py
df_a = pd.DataFrame({
    'country': ['Europe', 'Europe', 'USA', 'Africa'],
    'year': [2022, 2020, 2023, 2021]
})
df_b = pd.DataFrame({
    'country': ['Europe', 'USA', 'Africa', 'USA', 'Europe'],
    'year': [2023, 2022, 2022, 2023, 2022],
    'amount': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
})
```

The output would be:

```
  country  year  amount
0  Europe  2022    50.0
1  Europe  2020    50.0
2     USA  2023    40.0
3  Africa  2021     NaN
```

Comment: Thanks @Nick, I tried the sample data you had provided with sql query in db-fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/VROavr1v), sql code seems to be giving different result as compared to python output you had provided, any ways for this, please share

Comment: @RavenSmith cottontail is indeed correct; because it's a left join the mask has to happen first to ensure all values from `df_a` are in the result. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Nick, I just noticed something, when I added a row in first df like 'Europe' and year 2020, sql gives a different result, you can check this example I've used [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/WQdeiOaB)

Comment: @RavenSmith sorry, I made the same misinterpretation as cottontail. I've corrected the code